# Unable to cast string to OfficeOpenXml

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am exporting table data to excel, but I get an error with the following details:
`System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelColumn'.'`.
I am using ExcelPackage package.

My code method is:

```cs
public void ExportToExcel()
        {
//FECTH DATA FROM DB
            List<ExcellExport> excellExports = db2.MaintenanceWorkFlows.Select(
                x => new ExcellExport
                {
                    MaintenanceId = x.MaintenanceId,
                    RequisitionNo = x.RequisitionNo,
                    MaintenanceDate = x.MaintenanceDate,
                    MaintenanceFrequency = x.MaintenanceFrequency,
                    ContractNo = x.ContractNumber,
                    ContractorName = x.ContractorName,
                    MaintenanceStatus = x.MaintenanceStatus
                }).ToList();
```

from here. I use the excelpackage to export the data

```cs
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();

            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("ExpiredContracts");
            ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Report";
            ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "Expired Contracts Report";

            ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Date";
            ws.Cells["B1"].Value = string.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyy} at {0:H:mm tt}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

            ws.Cells["A4"].Value = "MainenanceId";
            ws.Cells["B4"].Value = "RequisitionNo";
            ws.Cells["C4"].Value = "MaintenanceDate";
            ws.Cells["D4"].Value = "MaintenanceFrequency";
            ws.Cells["E"].Value = "ContractNo";
            ws.Cells["F4"].Value = "ContractorName";
            ws.Cells["G4"].Value = "MaintenanceStatus";

            int rowStart = 10;

            foreach(var item in excellExports)
            {
                ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.MaintenanceId;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.RequisitionNo;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.MaintenanceDate;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.MaintenanceFrequency;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.ContractNo;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.ContractorName;
                ws.Cells[string.Format("A{0}", rowStart)].Value = item.MaintenanceStatus;
            }
            ws.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.Openxmlformats.Officedocument-spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition" ,"attachment:filename="+"ExpiredContractsReport.xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
            Response.End();


        }
```

What am I doing wrong? I have looked at codes but none solves the issue.

Comment: and which line here is problematic? Error seem self-explaining

Comment: this is the part with the error : `ws.Cells["A:AZ"].AutoFitColumns();`

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642950/auto-column-width-in-epplus/15643058

Comment: i changed to `ws.Column(1).AutoFit()` but I got this after running it `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Comment: place a breakpoint on this line and use the mouse to investigate, which instance is not there `ws` or `Column(1)`

Comment: it is ok upto  here: `ws.Column(1).AutoFit();` then break at `Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());`